# Highlighted tabs in chrome extension API

Tags: tabs, google-chrome-extension, highlight, browser-tab

Please give me an advice on chrome extension API. I'm trying to write a code that would do the same thing like when I highlight all the tabs in chrome, click the right button on them and choose reload, so all the tabs get reloaded together at once. I have no problems with highlighting the tabs, but how can I apply some operation to those highlighted tabs ?

Comment: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html

Answer (score 0):

Applying operations on a set of tabs requires passing the tab ID(s) to the respective methods in the [chrome.tabs API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html).

So, in your case, simply remember the tab IDs of the tabs you highlighted programmatically (or use [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) to fetch them) and call [chrome.tabs.reload](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-reload) sequentially, passing a single tab ID per invocation. (Unfortunately, the API does not accept an array of IDs, so you'll have to pass them one by one.)